# load Doc2Vec model and get new sentence's vectors for test

Tags: nlp, word2vec, gensim, doc2vec

I have read lots of examples regarding doc2vec, but I couldn't find any answer. Like a real example, I want to build a model with doc2vec and then train it with some ML models. after that, how can I get the vector of a raw string with the exact trained Doc2vec model? because I need to predict with my ML model with the same size and logical vector

Answer (score 0):

There are a collection of example Jupyter (aka IPython) notebooks in the gensim `docs/notebooks` directory. You can view them online at:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/tree/develop/docs/notebooks

But they'll be in your gensim installation directory, if you can find that for your current working environment.

Those that include `doc2vec` in their name demonstrate the use of the `Doc2Vec` class. The most basic intro operates on the 'Lee' corpus that's bundled with gensim for use in its unit tests. (It's really too small for real Doc2Vec success, but by forcing smaller models and many training iterations the notebook just barely manages to get some consistent results.) See:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/doc2vec-lee.ipynb

It includes a section on inferring a vector for a new text:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/doc2vec-lee.ipynb

Note that inference is performed on a *list of string tokens*, not a raw string. And those tokens should have been preprocessed/tokenized the same way as the original training data for the model, so that the vocabularies are compatible. (Any unknown words in a new text are silently ignored.)

Note also that especially on short texts, it often helps to provide a much-larger-than-default value of the optional `steps` parameter to `infer_vector()` - say 50 or 200 rather than the default 5. It may also help to provide a starting `alpha` parameter more like the training default of 0.025 than the method-default of 0.1.